# JavaScript Circular reference issue?

Tags: javascript

My question is related to circular references in JavaScript.
Basically I am trying to create a js array and put the same array as a property inside itself.
While I tried the below code on my firebug console, i could not reason why the below outputs happened.

```
var a = [];
a[a]=a;

//delete(a[a[a[a]]]); edited
delete(a[a][a][a][a]);

console.log(a[a]);
//says undefined. but i deleted the 4th nested level ??

console.log(a);
//still gives []. so a exists.
```

My question is, I deleted only `a[a][a][a][a]`, so but the outer properties should still stay right? like `a[a]` & `a[a][a]` should not be `undefined` right?.

### edit

but when i assign the array as a property with key as itself and inspected the same on firebug, I am able to expand both the key and value of the object in nested fashion, If it gets as null as key it should be visible in the inspector right?

Comment: Javascript assigns arrays by reference, not by value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- As you say it's a circular reference - so there is no "*4th nested level*" but only one which goes back to itself
- You shouldn't use `a` as a property here. Property names must be strings in JS, and it will just stringify `[]` to `""` automatically when using the empty array as a property name. You're lucky the stringification did not take the non-numeric property into account.

So what happens:

```
var a = [];
// OK an empty array.

a[a] = a;
a[""] = a;
// set the "" property of it to itself

delete(a[a[a[a ]]]);
delete a[a[a[a ]]]
delete a[a[a[""]]]
delete a[a[ a   ]]
delete a[a[ ""  ]]
delete a[ a      ]
delete a[ ""     ]
// remove the "" property from a

console.log(a[a]);
// is undefined now again

console.log(a);
// still gives []. Is still an array without any items.
```

Notice that `a[a][a][a] === a` so when you do `delete a[a][a][a][a]` it's just equivalent to `delete a[a]`. You can follow a circular reference infinitely often, but it is only *one* reference that exists and then gets deleted:

```
a[""] = a;
// set the "" property of it to itself again

delete(a[""][""][""][""]);
delete    a[""] [""] [""] [""]
delete (((a[""])[""])[""])[""]
delete ((  a    [""])[""])[""]
delete (        a    [""])[""]
delete               a    [""]
// remove the "" property from a again

console.log(a[""]);
// is undefined now again
```

Comment: i edited the question. what i meant was `a[a][a][a][a]`. u are right regarding the other one.

Comment: when i did the step `a[a] = a;` and inspected it in firebug. I can expand both key and its value in the same nested fashion. So the key getting converted to null is not visible there. Or am i wrong?

Comment: no idea what you are stepping in at, but when you evaluate the property reference then the `a` in `[a]` is getting stringified to the empty string. Maybe firebug shows the *value* of the `a` variable to be the nested object, but that does make absolutely no difference. You can replace every `a` in a property access with `""` and your script will work in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

What happens is like this:

- `a` has a **reference** to itself.
- `a[a]` gets the `value` that is located at the `string value` of `a` which is a reference to `a`.
- `a[a[a]]` get the `value` that is located at the `string value` of the result of `a[a]` which is a reference to `a`.

So you can tell that there is no true "*4th level*".

The `delete` reduces to `delete(a[a])`.

**Update:**

Since

```
a[a][a][a][a] = a[a][a][a] = a[a][a] = a[a] = a;
```

because `a[a]` returns `a` and you just apply the `[]` operator to `a` again.

So

`delete(a[a][a][a][a]);` becomes `delete(a[a]);` which becomes `delete(a[""]);`

**Update 2:**

Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TPCmM/).

```
var a = [];
a[a] = a;
console.log(a); // has 1 element
console.log(a[a] == a); //true
console.log(a[a] === a); // true
console.log(a == ""); // true

a[a][a][a].push("1");
console.log(a); // has 2 elements
console.log(a[a]); // this becomes undefined because a is no more ""

var b = [];
b[b] = b;
b.push("1");
console.log(b);
console.log(b[b]);
console.log(b[b] == b);
```

Comment: i edited the question. what i meant was `a[a][a][a][a]`.

Comment: +1: "i have bit more doubt in understanding the same. Pls see my edit in qn."